# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ravel'

Tags: python, numpy, attributeerror

The following block continues to return the same error and I don't understand why......Any help? I've imported numpy as np and defined both xx1 and xx2 but the code still returns the error. What could be causing the issue?

```
def plot_decision_regions(X,y,classifier,resolution=0.02):
    markers = ('s','x','o','^','v')
    colors = ('red','blue','lightgreen','gray','cyan')
    cmap = ListedColormap(colors[:len(np.unique(y))])
    x1_min = X[:,0].min() -1
    x1_max = X[:,0].max() +1
    x2_min = X[:,1].min() -1
    x2_max = X[:,1].max() +1
    xx1 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min,x1_max,resolution))
    xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x2_min,x2_max,resolution))
    Z = classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(),xx2.ravel()]).T)
    Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)
    plt.contourf(xx1,xx2,Z,alpha=0.3,cmap=cmap)
    plt.xlim(xx1.min(),xx1.max())
    plt.ylim(xx2.min(),xx2.max())
    for idx, cl in enumerate(np.unique(y)):
        plt.scatter(x=X[y==cl,0],y=X[y==cl,1],alpha=0.8,c=colors[idx],marker=markers[idx],label=cl,edgecolor='black')

        
>>> plot_decision_regions(X,y,classifier=ppn)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#68>", line 1, in <module>
    plot_decision_regions(X,y,classifier=ppn)
  File "<pyshell#67>", line 11, in plot_decision_regions
    Z = classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(),xx2.ravel()]).T)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ravel'
```

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `xx1 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min,x1_max,resolution))`, exactly what do you expect this to do? What do you think will be the value of `xx1` afterwards, and what do you think will be its type? Why? Did you try to check this, either by reading the documentation or by examining the value? Do you understand why it should not be possible to use `.ravel` on this result?

Comment: The error message suggests that line 11 is causing the issue. Do either of you suspect that it might be line 9? I agree that I would expect np.meshgrid() to return a list of coordinates including x1_max and x1_min which will be used as components of the decision regions. Agree?

Comment: Line 9 is where `xx1` is assigned. `xx1` is a `list`. Line 11 reports an error because ravel is not a method on Python's built-in `list`. Maybe, you meant to convert the `list` to a Numpy `Array` before assigning `xx1` (on line 9), like Nick suggested. Maybe you intended to call `ravel` on the individual elements of `xx1` and you need to iterate through the elements of `xx1` (on line 11).

Comment: " agree that I would expect np.meshgrid() to return a list of coordinates including x1_max and x1_min which will be used as components of the decision regions. Agree?" Yes. On line 9 you call `np.meshgrid`, which gives you a list. A list is not a Numpy array. On line 11 you try to use the list as if it were a Numpy array, which results in the error message. Error messages cannot tell you the ultimate cause of a problem, only the proximate cause. This is fundamental stuff about *how error messages work* which you should understand *before* trying to learn Numpy.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `np.meshgrid()` is a list.

> Return a list of coordinate matrices from coordinate vectors.

([Source](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html).)

Then xx1 and xx2 are lists, and you get this error.

You can use `np.array()` to convert a list to an array.

Comment: It's not *at all* clear that simply coercing the resulting lists back to array will result in something where applying `.ravel` will make sense, never mind stacking and transposing those two results again. Please try not to imply that types are an arbitrary obstruction or that knowing how to convert types is all that is needed to resolve problems caused by something being of the wrong type.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The question is about why the error occurs. The answer is about why the error occurs. If you feel it is substandard, I encourage you to write a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Your two best friends when debugging are the numpy docs, and a interactive test environment

The lines in question are:

```
xx1 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min,x1_max,resolution))
xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x2_min,x2_max,resolution))
np.array([xx1.ravel(),xx2.ravel()]).T
```

Let's do the arange with a simple range.  I won't get into how you pick the min and max.  But be careful with using a fraction step like `0.02`.  The endpoint treatment can be unpredicatable, and hence that actual number of elements in the `arange`.  `arange` warns about this.

```
In [205]: xx1 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,10))    
In [206]: xx1
Out[206]: [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]    
In [207]: xx1.ravel()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[207], line 1
----> 1 xx1.ravel()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ravel'
```

as `meshgrid` tells us, the result is a `list`, and a list does not have a `ravel`.  Are you clear as to why you are using `meshgrid` and `ravel`?  A simple `arange` shoud be enough.

Normally `meshgrid` is used with 2 or more aranges.  There's little benefit to using it with just one.

```
In [208]: xx1 = np.arange(0,10)
```

Now let's try to make array in the last line (using another `xx1` inplace of `xx2`):

```
In [209]: np.array([xx1,xx1]).T
Out[209]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 4],
       [5, 5],
       [6, 6],
       [7, 7],
       [8, 8],
       [9, 9]])
```

Note that if `xx2` had a different length - I haven't looked at whether the min/max do anthing to control that length. Plus there the fractional `step` issue that I previously mentioned.

```
In [210]: xx2 = np.arange(0,8)    
In [211]: np.array([xx1,xx2]).T
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[211], line 1
----> 1 np.array([xx1,xx2]).T

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.
```

This error message is a bit obscure, but it's the latest in a long sequence dealing with "ragged" arrays.  `numpy` can't make a numeric dtype array from arrays that differ in length.

Again I don't know what your ovrall goal is, but this should help isolate potential problems in constructing an array to feed to the classifier.